# Difference between these two bit.ly API ActionScript implementations?

Tags: apache-flex, api, actionscript, comparison, bit.ly

I'm new to Flex and wondering what the difference is between these two ActionScript implementations of the bit.ly API:

http://github.com/julien/as3_bitly

http://code.google.com/p/bitly-as3-api/

One thing I noticed is that one comes in .as files and the other's an .swc file.  Is one better than the other for learning Flex?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SWC is a precompiled declaration of functions and unless absolutely necessary for compilation reasons, I've never been much of a fan.

The latter of your links is more complete, however, and you can get the source files that were used to make that SWC [here](http://code.google.com/p/bitly-as3-api/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Env.API.Bitly/src/env/webapis/bitly). The first link appears to simply be a very basic demo for the creation of a bit.ly shortened URL that was committed once and never touched again compared to the second that looks to be a nearly fully implemented AS3 window to the API.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Are you aware of any other/better AS3 implmementations of the bit.ly API?  I'm looking to make a reporting application in Flex with stats retrieved via the API.

Comment: I am unaware of any others, only because I've never really needed to work with bit.ly - sorry I couldn't be of more help.